# When to convert unicode to string?

Tags: python

I am working on a project which aims to fetch some data from some websites and then stores into database. But these websites contains different charsets such as utf-8, gbk. The fetched data is unicode so i wonder when to convert to string is the right way. I convert to string immediately for now, but it seems that the python suggests to keep unicode as long as possible, i can't figure out why? Because we always don't know the charset of the unicode object.

Comment: Unicode is a superset of every other character set, so it's safe for holding your characters.

Answer (score 1):

`unicode`s don't *have* a charset; they are **pure text**. Only convert to a bytestring when storing or transmitting in a medium where only bytes are accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation to treat text in your apps are:

1. Get the input bytes (string encoded) from some place
2. Decode them into `Unicode` and work with `Unicode` inside your app.
3. Whenever you want to output the text, encode it.

If your fetching web pages, I've seen `BeautifulSoup` and other libraries that do the job for converting the incoming bytes in Unicode for you. So in your app, you can work with them in Unicode.

If you want to store it in a database, is probably that the database is encoded in `utf-8`, if not, learn what its encoding is and **when you're ready to write the info to the database**, encode it first.

```
text = text.encode('utf-8') # or the encode used by your DB
db.persist(text) # pseudocode here ;)
```

This way you a *unicode protection* layer in front of your app, for input and output.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A good DB adapter takes `unicode` and figures out the charset stuff for you.

Comment: Yes, i use `BeautifulSoup` to fetch data from website. But i thought the unicode i get from `BeautifulSoup` may not decode using 'utf-8' charset, so i can't not only convert to string using `.encode("utf-8")'. So here is the question: if i don't convert to string as soon as possible, i will be lost when i do some string process in my program such as regex matching.

Comment: Any unicode can be decoded, I don't understand quite well what you mean. About Regex, they can handle unicode well, you'll be fine applying regex to Unicode.